# RVM install ruby from local source

Tags: ruby, rvm

I can't believe the this isn't a more frequently asked question.

I want to install ruby 1.9.2, and I want it as part of my RVM installation. The link for 1.9.2 has since 404'd on the ruby-lang site, so I copied the tar.gz from the ruby github page, rezipped it into a tar.bz2 like rvm requires and dropped it into `~/.rvm/archives`

However, every time I call `rvm install 1.9.2-p320` it deletes the source tar.bz2 from `~/.rvm/archives` and tries to redownload the tar.bz2 from the ruby-lang site.

The `--force` and `--disable-binary` options do nothing to prevent the deleting and redownloading attempts.

Is there a way to point rvm explicitly to the source tar.bz2? I'd like to avoid compiling from source myself and then copying the directory into wherever rvm needs it.

**Note:** It looks like the ruby-lang ftp server is just down for the moment which explains why the download keeps failing, but my question still stands as this seems like good functionality for rvm to have.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The deletion of archive is controlled with `--verify-downloads` flag:

```
rvm install 1.9.2-p320 --verify-downloads 2 --disable-binary
```

Values for the `--verify-downloads` flag:

- `0` - has to have checksum and must validate
- `1` - does not have to have checksum, if available must validate
- `2` - continue even the checksum does not validate

Comment: While i'd think that would work, and I appreciate the answer, it still tries to redownload...

`$ rvm install ruby-1.9.2-p320 --disable-binary --verify-downloads 2
Installing requirements for osx, might require sudo password.
Certificates in '/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem' already are up to date.
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/dlampa/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-1.9.2-p320 - #downloading ruby-1.9.2-p320, this may take a while depending on your connection...
Archive checksum did not match, downloading again.`

Comment: make sure your rvm is up to date `rvm get head` and oen a bug if it still fails => https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues

Comment: it did still fail, but i accepted the answer as this is clearly the appropriate way to install a source ruby.

I submitted an issue. https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/2097

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The front page of ruby-lang.org does mention that some services would be down, I'd suggest waiting for them to get their services back up and trying again.

http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2013/08/06/status-issue/

Answer (score 0):

rvm usage clearly said

```
rvm [Flags] [Options] Action
```

The correct syntax for your problem is

```
rvm --verify-downloads 2 --disable-binary install 1.9.2-p320
```

rvm will check the `flags` and `options` first before executing any `action`