# RVM fails installing Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I'm trying to install an older Ruby version via RVM but the installation fails with an error I've never seen before. I've already changed the `rvm_max_time_flag` but it didn't help. What can I do here?

```
rvm install 1.9.3p484
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.9/x86_64/ruby-1.9.3p484.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
Certificates in '/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem' already are up to date.
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/nandersen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3p484, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-1.9.3p484 - #downloading ruby-1.9.3p484, this may take a while depending on your connection...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
The requested url does not exist(22): 'http://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/./ruby-1.9.3p484.tar.bz2'
Checking fallback: http://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/./ruby-1.9.3p484.tar.bz2
Checking fallback: http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/./ruby-1.9.3p484.tar.bz2
No fallback URL could be found, try increasing timeout with:

    echo "export rvm_max_time_flag=20" >> ~/.rvmrc

There has been an error fetching the ruby interpreter. Halting the installation.
```

Comment: The URL it's constructing is incorrect - it should be http://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.9/ruby-1.9.3-p484.tar.bz2

Comment: Can I specify the URL I wan't to use somewhere @sevenseacat?

Comment: I don't know RVM, but try using `rvm install 1.9.3-p484` instead. Maybe that will fix the URL.

Answer (score 7):

1) Make sure you are using latest RVM

`rvm get head`

2) and then install new ruby

`rvm install ruby-2.3`

Answer (score 3):

It says that the URL does not exist OR the URL has no ruby version available for download.

Try installing with a compatible ruby-gem version:

```
rvm install 1.9.3p484 --rubygems 2.0.9
```

## OR

**Update**

Are you sure that you are using an updated version of RVM?

```
rvm get head
rvm install 1.9.3
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks but when I use `rvm install 1.9.3` it uses a different version than `p484`.

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

Do `rvm list known`. If it does not list the ruby version one is after, one can still install that version from local source. Some ruby versions are not maintained and won't be listed and rvm might generate the wrong URL.

For example installing **ruby-1.9.3-p484** goes like this:

First download the ruby archive into RVMs archives folder:

`cd ~/.rvm/archives; wget http://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.9/ruby-1.9.3-p484.tar.bz2`

Then install with the following flags:

`rvm install 1.9.3-p484 --verify-downloads 2 --disable-binary`

## Explanation

I had to do it like this after not being able to do:
`rvm install ruby-1.9.3p484`

Since the above command generated this error:

> The requested url does not exist(22): 'https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/./ruby-1.9.3p484.tar.bz2'
>   Checking fallback: https://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/./ruby-1.9.3p484.tar.bz2
>   No fallback URL could be found, try increasing timeout with:
>
> echo "export rvm_max_time_flag=20" >> ~/.rvmrc
>
> There has been an error fetching the ruby interpreter. Halting the installation.

Also see this SO answer [RVM install ruby from local source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18084283/rvm-install-ruby-from-local-source)

Answer (score 0):

Also faced a similar issue,
`rvm install 2.5.x` did not work,
Saw the following error:

```
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/sdorwat/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.x, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-2.5.x - #downloading ruby-2.5.x, this may take a while depending on your connection...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404
The requested url does not exist(22): 'https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/./ruby-2.5.x.tar.bz2'
Checking fallback: https://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/./ruby-2.5.x.tar.bz2
No fallback URL could be found, try increasing timeout with:
.
.
There has been an error fetching the ruby interpreter. Halting the installation.
```

Following command worked:
`rvm install ruby-2.5`

Answer (score -4):

I resolve that just changing the mod of the path of rvm

```
sudo chmod 777 -R /path/to/rvm
```

in my case: /usr/local/rvm

Comment: Nice idea, I'll try that next time it occurs.

Comment: Never set any file to 777 permissions. It's a serious security risk.