# Error installing Ruby 2.2.2 with RVM on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ruby, rvm, ubuntu-14.04, ruby-2.2

Here's what.
I first did:

```
rvm get stable
rvm install ruby-2.2.2
```

No deal. It shows me the following:

```
$ rvm install ruby-2.2.2
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: ubuntu/14.04/i386/ruby-2.2.2.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for ubuntu.
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /home/myuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-2.2.2 - #downloading ruby-2.2.2, this may take a while depending on your connection...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:19 --:--:--     0Warning: Transient problem: timeout Will retry in 2 seconds. 3 retries left.
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:19 --:--:--     0Warning: Transient problem: timeout Will retry in 2 seconds. 2 retries left.
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:19 --:--:--     0Warning: Transient problem: timeout Will retry in 2 seconds. 1 retries left.
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:19 --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: cache.ruby-lang.org
There was an error(6).
Checking fallback: http://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.2/ruby-2.2.2.tar.bz2
Checking fallback: http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.2/ruby-2.2.2.tar.bz2
No fallback URL could be found, try increasing timeout with:

    echo "export rvm_max_time_flag=20" >> ~/.rvmrc

There has been an error fetching the ruby interpreter. Halting the installation.
```

I increased the timeout as told:

```
echo "export rvm_max_time_flag=20" >> ~/.rvmrc
```

But no deal. I also did `rvm get head` and did it all over again with higher timeouts but it was still no good.

what can I do to correctly install ruby-2.2.2 on ubuntu?

Comment: See if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23339379/rvm-fails-installing-ruby

Comment: Its doesn't. It may be the same problem. Not sure though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I feel lame, but the problem was that my VM's internet connection was failing. (I guess I missed Troubleshooting-101, hehe)

I changed the PC's network and the Virtual Box VM didn't update or connect to the new network. To add to the issue, **none** of the commands ( `rvm get stable`; `rvm get head`; `rvm install ruby-2.2.2` ) raised a warning, so I was led to think it was something else.

"Errors should never pass silently." (The Zen of Python)